# Ember.js Multiple Selection in a Table

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

I'm newbie in Ember.js framework, and I have a problem, I need a multiple selection of rows in a table. 
 I'm using jQuery Datatables, with Ember-Data, and I need to have an ID of the selected rows, something like push to the array and I have no clue how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For multiple selection, make sure you initialize the table with the `select` option set to "multi":

```
this.$("#myDT").DataTable({
    select: "multi"
});
```

When you want to get the list of all the rows selected, use a jQuery selector to get all the rows that have the `selected` class and get their data. In this example, the ID is the first column in the data, hence the `[0]`

```
var selectedRows = Ember.$('#myDT tbody tr.selected');
var selectedIDs = [];
Ember.$.each(selectedRows, function (i, element) {
    selectedIDs.push(table.row(element).data()[0]);
});
```

You can read more about DataTables API (for things like getting row data using the `row.data()` method here: https://datatables.net/reference/api/